# How to visualise /add Arabidopsis T-DNA Lines As Tracks On IGV

Tags: sam, visualization, transcriptome, igv

We have done some RNA-Seq on Arabidopsis T-DNA lines and mapped the reads on to Arabidopsis genome. Now we wanted to confirm the T-DNA deletion of those lines by loading them on IGV. As a control we also wanted to load T-DNA lines as tracks on IGV to make sure that the T-DNA lines we chose were correct. I am wondering where can i get bam files for those confirmed T-DNA lines?

Comment: Sorry I might be missing something. You mentioned mapping the reads onto the genome. The output is a bam file right? You can just create an index for it and load it into IGV

Comment: Are you asking how to see the location and names of all the T-DNA lines, like shown [here](http://signal.salk.edu/cgi-bin/tdnaexpress)?